# R - Inflação acumulada

Tags: r

Olá, gostaria de uma ajuda na seguinte missão, com base na tabela do IPCA-mensal (série histórica), adicionar um campo com a inflação acumulada anual, onde o processo recomeça a cada ano.

Para o cáluclo da inflação acumulada, usa-se o juros composto, onde temos a seguinte fórmula:
Inflação Acumulado = (((1 + (inflação do mês/100)) * inflação acumulada anterior) + inflação do mes)

Tentei usar o soma simples, mas o resultado final é divergente do resultado anual final, por isso, a necessidade de usar juros composto.

Meu dataset, ou data.frame, (listaDF) de entrada tem o seguintes campos:
1- Data: (mes de apuração)
2- Inflação: Inflaçlão do mês.

Neste caso gostaria de ter como saída, uma data set igual o de entrada acrescentado de uma coluna com o juros acumulado, onde ele seria apurado por ano, ou seja, a cada inicio de ano, a contagem recomeça.
Dataset final:

1- Data: (mes de apuração)
2- Inflação: Inflaçlão do mês.
3 - Inflação acumulada: Inflação acumulada durante o ano de apuração.

Tentei usar o script abaixo no RStudio, mas ele não cria o campo, e nem da mensagem de erro.

Como irei realizar o processo em várias fontes, imaginei usar uma função para deixar mais limpo e funcional.

Dataset de entrada (exemplo):

```
lista <- list(a = c('1991-10-01', '1991-11-01', '1991-12-01', '1992-01-01','1992-02-01'), 
              b = c(0.5, 0.6, 0.8, 1.2, 1.4))
```

Onde "a" é o mês de refência e "b" é a inflação.

tentativa utilizada sem sucesso (Não cria o campo) e não dá mensagem de erro.

Obs.1: Gostaria que fosse via função pois o processo vai ser realizado em várias tabelas.
Obs.2: Não achei uma função/pacote com essa função

```
lista <- list(a = c('1991-10-01', '1991-11-01', '1991-12-01', '1992-01-01','1992-02-01'), 
              b = c(0.5, 0.6, 0.8, 1.2, 1.4))
lista

listaDF <- as.data.frame(lista)

Acum <- function(){
  ano1 = format(df$Data[1], format = "%Y")
  ano1 = as.integer(ano1)
  anomes <- paste(ano1, mes)
  anomes
  jur1 = 0
  acum_jur = 0
  #df$acum_jur <- vector(df, length(df$data))
  #i = 1;
  for (x in df$Data){
    dia3 = as.Date(x)
    ano2 = (format(dia3, format = "%Y"))
    ano2 <- as.integer(ano2)
    mes <- format(dia3, format = "%m")
    jur = df$tx_jur[df$Data == dia3]
    if (ano2 == ano1)
    {
      anomes <- paste(ano2, mes)
      acum_jur1 = (((1 + (jur/100)) * acum_jur) + jur)
      acum_jur <- acum_jur1
      df$tx_acum[df$Data == dia3] <- round(acum_jur1, 2)
      #df$acum_jur[[i]] <- round(acum_jur1, 2)
    }
    else
    {
      ano1 = ano1 + 1
      anomes <- paste(ano2, mes)
      acum_jur1 = df$tx_jur[df$Data == dia3]
      acum_jur <- acum_jur1
      df$tx_acum[df$Data == dia3] <- round(acum_jur1, 2)
      #df$acum_jur[[i]] <- round(acum_jur1, 2)
    }
  }
}

listaDF$new_column <- Acum()
listaDF
```

Comment: Olá PNETO. Coloque um exemplo do `data.frame` completo que você precisa como saída. Essa função que você fez: Ela calcula errado? Não calcula? A inflação do ano não é só somar todos os valores do ano? Veja dicas de como melhorar a sua pergunta [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%C3%AAncia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%C3%AAs) e [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu acredito que a função *cumprod* já faz o cálculo da taxa acumulada que você procura:

```
taxas <- c(0.5, 0.6, 0.8)
taxas
# [1] 0.5 0.6 0.8
taxas_acumuladas <- cumprod((taxas/100) + 1) - 1
taxas_acumuladas
# [1] 0.00500000 0.01103000 0.01911824
```

Então a parte difícil do seu problema seria a divisão dos dados em blocos. Eu fiz uma solução dividindo em blocos com *split* que aparece mais abaixo, mas depois percebi que se obtém o mesmo resultado de forma mais simples simplesmente agrupando por ano:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
    a = c('1991-10-01','1991-11-01','1991-12-01','1992-01-01','1992-02-01'),
    b = c(0.5, 0.6, 0.8, 1.2, 1.4)
  )

df <- df %>%
  mutate(a = as.Date(a),
         y = year(a)) %>%
  arrange(a)

# solução agrupando...
sol1 <- df %>% 
  group_by(y) %>% 
  mutate(
    tx_acum = cumprod((b/100)+1)-1
  )

# ou dividindo em blocos...
split_df <- split(df, df$y)
cum_taxes <- map(split_df, ~ (cumprod((.$b/100) + 1) - 1))
sol2 <- do.call(rbind,
              map2(split_df, cum_taxes, ~ tibble(.x, cum_taxes = .y)))
```